# How do you populate an Entity with foreign keys from an Array in Symfony2/doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Consider an entity which has a foreign key.  We receive an array which contains the foreign key as an integer and we want to populate the current entity from the array (this could be either an update or a create, makes no difference).  So far I have been unable in the documentation to find an example of how to perform this update in the "symfony2/doctrine" way.

If we change the type of the private variable to be an integer instead of an object of the type of the Foreign entity, we lose the ORM mapping/auto-instantiation/etc.  If we leave as is, we cannot set it with a simple integer.

Doctrine documentation dictates we shall not access the entity manager from within an Entity (for the purpose of "find"ing the foreign entity from the key before setting current entities value) and anyway I haven't found documentation of how to do it if I wanted to.  Best practices dictate that population of an object from an array should occur as an object method on that object.  Common sense dictates that a simple array should be supported and should not require end user/controller to know to create the foreign entity.

Can someone point me in the direction of sanity?

Example Code:

```
<?php
namespace Prefix\MyBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
class Item
{
    private $itemid;

    /*
             * --- omitted for brevity ---
             */
    private $categoryid;
    public function getItemid()
    {
        return $this->itemid;
    }
    /**
     * --- omitted for brevity again ---
     */
    public function setCategoryid(\Prefix\MyBundle\Entity\Category $categoryid = null)
    {
        $this->categoryid = $categoryid;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getCategoryid()
    {
        return $this->categoryid;
    }
    public function fromArray($data = array())
    {
        $updated = false;
        if ( isset($data['Category']) )
        {
            /* We know that $data['Category'] will be an int */
            $this->setCategoryid($data['Category']); //Fails invalid type!
            $updated = true;
        }
        return $updated;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the cardinality of your entities?

Comment: for the example Item to Category, let's assume many to one. Item->has a ->category.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use doctrine you shouldn't be working with foreign keys (
but with category objects. So in fact you should have converted the id to category outside your function.

Another option is to add a new column called category which is of type integer and you set that directly so that you know have 2 class variables pointing to the same object but one has the relation the other just the id

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne...
 */
protected $category;
/**
 * @Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $categoryid;

public function setCategory(\Prefix\MyBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
{
    $this->category = $category;

    return $this;
 }
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category;
}
public function setCategoryId($categoryid = null)
{
    $this->categoryid = $categoryid;

    return $this;
 }
public function getCategoryId()
{
    return $this->categoryid;
}
```

Comment: So it sounds like you are saying that I should just call a findOneById for category from the controller before updating the item?  That just seems wrong to me.  It almost feels like maybe there is a missing business logic layer between the controller and the entity,  that entity is not in fact the symfony2/doctrine representation of the model, but is instead supposed to just be an auto-generated db layer with no business logic?

Comment: With doctrine (ORM) you have to change your mindset. Don't think like a database. In your controller you should look for the entity first. Of course it is stupid to fetch it from the database but than use the proxy class $em->getReference(..., $categoryid) and than it looks like a category object and your code doesn't break.

Comment: With the additional comment, this gets to the heart of the problem and explains the "doctrine" way of doing things.  However I have to mention for anyone reading this later that adding an additional foreign key property is absolutely pointless and is just a distraction.  It doesn't in anyway fix the issue, because you will still need to populate the entity correctly using the process mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have to create your `Category` Object (owning side, many side), then fetch every `Item` object from db (you have an array of integer that are IDs, so you can do something like `->findById()` or a custom DQL query where you can fetch them into a shot). Subsequently you have to call, for every fetched object, a `->setItems()` or `->addItem()` and use `->persist(); ->flush();` of entity manager.